# Meteor: How to return HTML in a global helper

Tags: javascript, mongodb, templates, meteor, spacebars

I have the the following helper which works fine:

```
UI.registerHelper('shortIt', function(stringToShorten, maxCharsAmount){
  if(stringToShorten.length > maxCharsAmount){
    return stringToShorten.substring(0, maxCharsAmount) + ' ...';
  }
  return stringToShorten;
});
```

It's used like this:

```
{{#each newsEventsData}}
...
     <p class="text-muted"> {{shortIt this.description 150}} <a href="{{pathFor route = 'newsAndEventsPage'}}" 
    class="textlink">read more </a></p>

...
{{/each}}
```

`newsEventsData`is just a local helper that returns all documents in the collection.

The problem: `description`is a string with HTML tags as I'm using the **summernote** text editor. This is how a json looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : "EEuDg6DBNHrmAhWqa",
    "title" : "A Dummy News Edited",
    "description" : "\n\t\t            \t\tLorem <b>ipsum</b> dicta sunt explicabo. <i>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut Management\n\t\t            \t</i>",
    "type" : "news",
    "lastmodifiedAt" : "Mon, 09 May 2016 12:17:33",
    "publishedAt" : "Mon, 09 May 2016 12:17:33",
    "publishedRawFormat" : ISODate("2016-05-09T10:17:33.007Z"),
    "keywords" : [ 
        ""
    ],
    "modifiedAt" : "Mon, 09 May 2016 05:03:05"
}
```

If I used `{{{description}}}` on the other hand, I couldn't user the `shortIt` helper anymore. How to solve this dilemma?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the substring is not valid HTML?

Comment: @MasterAM: as it is coming from the admins (only they're allowed to add new news and event entries) plus it's the content of the summernote text editor, I assume it's going to be valid.

Comment: You are right about the entire string, but I don't suppose they check that the 150th char is not in the middle of a tag.

Comment: Ahh ok. Now I understand what you're saying. Very good point. Hm ...what now? The description is shortened to show a READ MORE link after the dots.

Comment: @AmirRahbaran Why do you not use `{{{shortIt this.description 150}}}`?

Comment: I would probably add a text field for the intro text where the text originated from or strip the HTML from the text on the server and generate the intro text from that (save it as part of the document)

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart: Tried it before, but then the output looks like this: 
Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dicta sunt explicabo. <i>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut Man ... read more

Comment: @MasterAM: sounds good, I'll give it try. Thanks to both of you.